# Writing to a File in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, direct-runner

I am running WordCount program in Windows using Apache Beam via DirectRunner.I can see the output files getting created in a temp folder(under src/main/resources/).But the write to the output file is getting failed.
Below is the code snippet:

```
p.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("src/main/resources/input.txt"))
                .apply(Regex.split(" "))
                .apply(Count.<String>perElement())
                .apply(ToString.elements())
                .apply(TextIO.write().to("src/main/resources/output.txt"));
```

Please let me know the format it expects for the output directory/file
Thanks in advance

Following is the error :
Adding Exception:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for i
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:447)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchResources(FileSystems.java:174)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.delete(FileSystems.java:321)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.cleanup(FileBasedSink.java:905)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles.processElement(WriteFiles.java:376)

Comment: When saying that a program fails, please always include the compete printout of the error. Just knowing that your program didn't work is not enough to help you fix it.

Comment: Adding Exception:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find registrar for i
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:447)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:111)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchResources(FileSystems.java:174)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.delete(FileSystems.java:321)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.cleanup(FileBasedSink.java:905)
 at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardedBundles.processElement(WriteFiles.java:376)

Comment: I have updated the question with the print out of the error.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beam currently doesn't handle Windows paths very well. See associated JIRAs, e.g. [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2298). Perhaps try specifying the absolute path using `file://` ?

Comment: Using file:// also didn't work.I was able to run successfully in Unix box.As you mentioned, this might be an issue with Windows

Answer (score 0):

Summary: you can use the "/"  character as a standin for the drive the process is running on, e.g. if your output file is located at

> "C:/myFile"

write

```
TextIO.write().to("/myFile"));
```

Longer answer:

Even after the issue mentioned in jkff's answer ([this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2298)) was resolved, I could only make the way they specified work for input, not for output.

The javadoc in the [LocalFileSystem](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/LocalFileSystem.java) class says

```
 * <p>Windows OS:
 *
 * <ul>
 *   <li>pom.xml
 *   <li>C:/Users/beam/Documents/pom.xml
 *   <li>C:\\Users\\beam\\Documents\\pom.xml
 *   <li>file:/C:/Users/beam/Documents/pom.xml
 *   <li>file:///C:/Users/beam/Documents/pom.xml
 * </ul>
 */
```

but none of these worked for the method

```
TextIO.write().to(String filenamePrefix))
```

However, using release version 2.12.0, I was able to write to a file on the same drive by using "/" as the root directory, i.e. instead of "C:/myDirectory/myFile", I used "/myDirectory/myFile". Of course, this way, you can only write to files on the same drive, but given that DirectRunner should only be used for testing, this might be good enough for many cases.